# isc-dhcp-server and dnsmasq is not working in Virt Manager(debian) KVM

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, libvirt

I am trying to make a DHCP server in a VM what I pass a PCI ethenet adaptor to.
with dnsmasq I get the "interface ens7 does not exist"
dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=ens7
port=53
```

I tryed isc-dhcp-server but i get

```
No subnet declaration for ens7(no Ipv4 addresses)
*** Ignoring reqests on ens7
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpcd.conf

```
authoritative;
subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224{
 range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
}

Thanks

I try both dnsmasq and isc-dhcp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server may be connected to multiple network subnets. To start DHCP server, at least one subnet must be defined within the DHCP configuration file `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`.

Below is the simplest example of DHCP configuration file:

```
subnet 10.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.1.1.3 10.1.1.254;
}

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
}
```

Use nano or your favorite text editor to make this change below all the commented lines.

This configuration file instructs DHCP server to listen for DHCP client requests on subnet `10.1.1.0` with netmask `255.255.255.0`. Furthermore, it will assign IP addresses in range `10.1.1.3 – 10.1.1.254`. It also defines an empty definition for subnet with network ID `192.168.0.0`.

Alter the above code with your subnet and insert it into `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. When ready, restart your DHCP server with ( restart command may vary ) :

```
$ sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server
```

Comment: I have in the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf  ````authoritative;
subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224{
 range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
}
```